# Field calculator expressions in graphical modeler (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-modeler

In QGIS 3.18.  I am trying to build a model that will be used by others for a repetitive workflow involving a series of field calculator expressions.  The idea is to **create a new field**, **populate it** via an expression that I give the model, and then in subsequent steps, **apply additional expressions** to the attribute values.

The issue is that the *inputs* (several fields from the same layer) that will be used to calculate the values for the new, created field *will not always be the same each time*, and the layer may also not. I would like to have, say, 5 fields in the model, and **have the model prompt the user each time to select which fields they should be** (and which layer they should come from).

I have entered these 5 general fields into the model, but I need to be able to refer to these general (not-yet-actually-selected) fields in the Field Calculator algorithm from the Algorithms list.

- However, *the 'fields and values' element of the Field Calculator does not seem to identify these fields* I have created for the model; it seems I have to select real, actual fields from an existing layer.
- This does *not* seem to be the case for the Expression item in the Inputs list: when inserting an expression there, my 5 created fields show up and I can select them and put them in my expression.  However, this is an Input, not an Algorithm, and it does not allow me to specify an Output for that process (my new field).

I'm thinking since the option to select my model fields is possible for the Expression input, **there may be a way to do this with the Field Calculator algorithm**. What am I not seeing how to do here?

Comment: Don't know if this one can help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/386057/88814 or https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/382555/88814